# Why does R(gdal) mangle data when converting to geojson?

Tags: gdal, r, geojson, rgdal

I've encountered issues with projections in .geojson files created by rgdal, but I never thought it would destroy my data, until I tried this (reproducible example):

```
downloader::download("http://census.edina.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/England_lad_2011_gen_clipped.tar.gz", destfile = "cuas.zip")
untar("cuas.zip")
cuas_shp <- raster::shapefile("England_lad_2011_gen_clipped.shp")
tmap::qtm(cuas_shp)
rgdal::writeOGR(cuas_shp, "cuas-ogr", "OGRGeoJSON", "GeoJSON")
cuas_ogr <- rgdal::readOGR("cuas-ogr", "OGRGeoJSON")
tmap::qtm(cuas_ogr ) # fails - something wrong with the data
library(sp) # plot using normal methods
plot(cuas_shp)
plot(cuas_ogr)
```

There are more examples I can show. It seems the geojsonio package does not solve these issues either. Ask if you'd like more reproducible examples - want to check I'm not missing anything obvious first though.

(Also not the projection seems to be missing in the geojson example.)

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what these lines are doing? or what you expected it to do compared to what you actually get? You did of course remember that GeoJSON is really only supposed to exist as WGS84?

Comment: My rgdal flat out errors in reading that geojson with `Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) : 
  Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data: 655604.700 657534.101`. Its not WGS84...

Comment: "fails" how? After manually adding a "crs" (for epsg:27700) to the geoJSON, I see mostly grey but a few white polygons. Are the white ones the problem? I suspect they go anticlockwise instead of clockwise or something... plot() with a fill seems to work, so maybe `qtm` isn't behaving...